# Get Size Of Schema Using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, schema, multi-tenant

i try get size of schema from name of subdomain..
name of subdomain in schema public,

on controller.rb

```
@account = Account.find_by_subdomain(params[:subdomain])
@itemlist = Account.find(:all,:select => 'subdomain')
@schemasize = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '}+@itemlist.to_s+%q{') As bigint) )  As schema_size}).to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i
```

get localhost:3000/namesubdomain

output on command prompt

```
 (21.0ms)  select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table
_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schem
a = '[#<Account subdomain: "namesubdomain">]') As bigint) ) As schema_size
```

i want output on command prompt such as

```
   (151.0ms)  select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(tabl
e_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_sche
ma = 'namesubdomain') As bigint) ) As schema_size
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@itemlist.to_s` will render the object as a String.  Since the object is actually an Array rendering as a string will just output information about the Array instead of the contents.  What you probably want is either:

```
@itemlist.first.subdomain
```

or:

```
@itemlist.map(&:subdomain).join(" ")
```

Comment: error output.. 

  (4.0ms)  select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table_
schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema
 = '#<Account:0x5ea3400>') As bigint) ) As schema_size

Comment: Apparently, the default rendering of your object doesn't either define `to_s` ;) Use `subdomain` instead - updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for sending me lesson. It is very helpful :)